# Views Data Export Not working for current page

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I am using [View Data Export](http://htt://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) to export users in csv.
I am using a page view. Fields, User Name, Email. Same fields in Data Export display type and filters.

[image]

In Data Export display, using Parent Sort Checked.

Here are the page and Data Export Display using same settings.

[image]

Data Export Display.

[image]

On Page Display I am showing 5 users, with full pager. On Data Export Display I am using 5 as well.

When I change page, goto next page on /export-user, CSV Icon cant export users other than first 5 no matter on which page I am.

[image]

So the csv Icon shows the same link on each page.

Any idea if I am missing something.

Comment: Check your argument in url and pass the same in your export link.

Comment: I have tried, but no use.

Comment: Have you set the same configuration in export view too??

Comment: Yes same configuration in both views.

Comment: Try to copy the link and paste it in browser url bar.

Comment: I have updated the question with more detail.

Comment: Pager link should be `?page=1` but in your screenshot it is `?attach=page`.?

Comment: Its icon's link. Not Pager. Image showing on each pager csv icon has same link.

Comment: Thats what I was saying, The icon link should be changed according to pager. So that same page argument will go to exportable view and the result of that view will be change accordingly.

Comment: Ok, and that is my question, why it is not changing. Am I missing somthing.

Comment: That is the bug in module I think. You can create a custom link.

Comment: What kind of custom link. Please answer fully rather just commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2478463#comment-9869047) is a patch that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems issues with the module itself. You can just use view's template file or [hook_views_pre_render()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) rather than attachment.

Append a link after views content or in footer called `Export CSV`.

Your code will be like this :

```
print l('Export CSV', 'userexport.csv', array('query' => array('page' => $_GET['page']));
```

Comment: It will not work, as I tried using `userexport.csv?attach=page&page=1` in url with csv link, but generating the same file. So will be no use of this.

Comment: Then I think the issue with the module itself. Ask in module's issue queue.